# Simple operator overload does not work

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this code:

```
template <typename T>
class EasyPtr {
    T* data;
    public:
    EasyPtr(T* data): data(data){}
    EasyPtr(const EasyPtr<T>&)=delete;
    EasyPtr(EasyPtr<T>&&) = delete;
    ~EasyPtr(){
        delete data;
    }
    operator T*(){
        return data;
    }
    EasyPtr & operator = (T* data) {
        this -> data = data;
    }
    T& operator *() {
        return *data;
    }
    T& operator [](size_t pos) {
        return data[pos];
    }
};
int main(){
    EasyPtr<int> p = new int[10];
    return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly it gives error:

```
In file included from easy_ptr_test.cpp:1:0:
./easy_ptr.hpp:23:20: error: declaration of ‘operator[]’ as non-function
./easy_ptr.hpp:23:18: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
./easy_ptr.hpp:23:27: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘pos’
easy_ptr_test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
easy_ptr_test.cpp:4:32: error: use of deleted function ‘EasyPtr<T>::EasyPtr(EasyPtr<T>&&) [with T = int]’
In file included from easy_ptr_test.cpp:1:0:
./easy_ptr.hpp:10:5: error: declared here
```

It is apparently a function declaration... do not understand why. Maybe there is a stupid mistake somewhere.

Comment: Your assignment operator is missing a return statement.

Comment: @K-ballo thats one issue... but it gives the same error after I fixed it

Comment: That line in main implicitly constructs a temporary `EasyPtr<int>` on the right-hand side. That temporary can be moved into `p`. The move of that temporary into `p` can even be elided, but in order for that to happen the move constructor still has to be accessible, hence the error. If you change it to `EasyPtr<int> p(new int[10])` it should work.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Why does it not calling the `operator=(T*)` ???

Comment: @texasbruce `#include <cstddef>` to use `size_t`

Comment: @texasbruce Because this is *initialization*, not assignment. Using `=` doesn't invoke the assignment operator when the object is being constructed. You can postpone the assignment to the next line and it should work (but you need a default-constructor for that also).

Comment: @texasbruce: I know that doesn't solve the problem, that's why I didn't posted it as an answer but as a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `size_t` is defined in the `cstddef` header, so you should `#include` that before using it. That should get rid of the error surrounding the declaration of your `operator[]`.

The error in `main` arises because of the way copy-initialization works. When you do

```
EasyPtr<int> p = x;
```

you are performing *copy-initialization*. If `x` is of type `EasyPtr<int>`, or a cv-qualified version of it or one of its derived classes, then the effect of this initialization is simply to call either the copy or move constructor of `EasyPtr<int>` (*not* the copy-assignment or move-assignment operator!) If `x` is of a different type, then `x` is first used to construct a *temporary* `EasyPtr<int>` object, and *then* the copy or move constructor of `EasyPtr<int>` is called to copy or move this temporary object into `p`. You are getting an error because the compiler wants to call the move constructor but you've deleted it. (Again, the copy-assignment and move-assignment operators are *not* called.)

Solutions:

1) explicitly define the move constructor

```
EasyPtr(EasyPtr<T>&& other): data(other.data) {
    other.data = nullptr;
}
```

2) explicitly default the move constructor (you probably don't want to do this for this particular class, because it'll lead to a double free, but this solution is included for the sake of completeness)

```
EasyPtr(EasyPtr<T>&&) = default;
```

3) use direct-initialization rather than copy-initialization

```
EasyPtr<int> p {new int[10]};
```

The last option is probably the one you want, since it looks like you don't want your objects to be copied or moved. In this case copy-initialization is just not going to work, so you should probably declare the converting constructor `explicit`, so the error message will be less confusing.

```
explicit EasyPtr(T* data): data(data){}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> EasyPtr<int> p = new int[10];
> ```

That line in main implicitly constructs a temporary `EasyPtr<int>` on the right-hand side. Conceptually, it looks like this:

> ```
> EasyPtr<int> p = EasyPtr<int>(new int[10]);
> ```

This temporary can be moved into `p`. If your compiler implements copy-elision, the move of that temporary into `p` can even be elided; but in order for that to happen the move constructor still has to be accessible. Because the move constructor is declared as `delete`'d, you receive the error. If you change it to `EasyPtr<int> p(new int[10])` the error should go away because you're no longer constructing `p` from another `EasyPtr` instance.